# Why one has to add a static dependency of a dynamic framework to final App target explicitly

Tags: ios, swift, linker, dependencies, frameworks

I have xcode project setup like:

```
FinalApp                             (A iOS App target)
   - ExcitingDynamic.framework       (A in-house dynamic framework target)
        - SomeOtherStatic.framewrok  (A 3rd party static framework target)
```

Now my `FinalApp` only uses public interface of `ExcitingDynamic.framework`.

If I build, I get error in my `FinalApp`:

```
import ExcitingDynamic    <- ERROR: Missing required module: SomeOtherStatic
```

So, I have to solve this by adding `SomeOtherStatic.framewrok` as a dependency in `FinalApp` too, like so:

```
FinalApp
   - ExcitingDynamic.framework
        - SomeOtherStatic.framewrok
   - SomeOtherStatic.framewrok
```

I hit build and it works fine.
Question: Why I have to explicitly add `SomeOtherStatic` framework to `FinalApp` target if it was already linked to `ExcitingDynamic`? Won't it be statically linked to `ExcitingDynamic`? and then app should find it automatically?

NOTE: I don't want to do embbeding (`SomeOtherStatic` in `ExitingDynamic`) as it's not recommended by Apple for iOS

Comment: You cant hide a framework in a framework. The only way would be to use a Swift Package

Comment: @loremipsum, I don't want to hide/embed it, I just want to know why the SomeOtherStatic framework has to be explicitly added to the app target, shouldn't it be automatically linked to ExitingDynamic framework (hence the static linking)?

Comment: You would think so but no Apple does not make that connection. Apple goes into detail in one of the WWDC presentations about packages, it was a few of years ago. I don't remember exactly which one.

Comment: I would say is because the ExitingDynamic framework  does not export the other framework so it is not seen by the app. It may be a problem inside the framework definition.

Comment: @PtitXav Can you elaborate what you mean by "export the other framework"? I don't intend to refer to any of the APIs from SomeOtherStatic framework from my app.

Comment: The problem may be in ExitingDynamic which may not set the required link with SomeOtherStatic when included in the app. But just a guest.